# Tips on optimizing this code that loads multiple files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

```
fname = dir('*sir');  
dayH = zeros(length(fname),1360,3600);
for i=1:length(fname)   
    dayH(i,:,:) = loadsir(fname(i).name);
end  


fname = dir('*sir');  
dayH = cell(1,length(fname));  
for i=1:2  
   dayH{i} = loadsir(fname(i).name); 
end
```

Basically it loads all my files. I have a separate .m file called loadsir that loads those specialized files. The output of the .sir files will be an array 1360x3600.

Right now that code is crashing saying, "Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements." I guess it's because 1360X3600 = 5,000,000 about?

Comment: you probably missed `;` somewhere inside the `loadsir.m`, so it attempts to display this 1360X3600 matrix

Comment: The thing is I didn't write loadsir... It should just work. The 2nd code on the bottom works but it loads it into {}. The problem with this is I can't save/load .mat files for later use. Any Ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Putting Serg's comment as an answer:

Most likely you missed a semicolon (`;`) somewhere in `loadsir`. Matlab then thinks you want to print the output, which it won't do due to the large number of elements.

Additionally, to prevent such things from happening in the future:

Matlab is an interpreted language, meaning, no compilation is necessary. Any and all code can be parsed while you type it, which allows for things like auto-correct. Of course, this sort of thing is included already in standard Matlab. If you don't already, code in Matlab's own editor every now and then. It warns you of such silly mistakes/errors (and a lot more), including but not limited to, via the right vertical bar in the editor. The little square at the top right of the window should always be *green*. If it's *orange* or *red*, there's things to be improved or corrected, respectively.

The right vertical bar is an overview of all the lines in your file that leave room for improvement. If a small orange/red bar appears somewhere, a mouseover will tell you what's wrong with what line. Clicking it will navigate the editor to the line, which will likely be wavy-underlined in either orange or red. Mouse-over the line often gives useful suggestions, and `<alt>+<enter>` is often enough to fix the simple mistakes. I find it an indispensable tool when developing larger applications in Matlab.

You can of course configure which errors/warnings this tool ("code analyzer", formerly "mlint") displays. Sometimes, there will be a warning about an inefficiency that you simply cannot work around. Add an OK-directive behind the line to suppress it (`%#ok`), but **don't** make a habit of suppressing anything and everything "annoying" because that will of course completely beat the purpose of the code analyzer :)

Comment: The thing is I didn't write loadsir... It should just work. The 2nd code on the bottom works but it loads it into {}. The problem with this is I can't save/load .mat files for later use. Any Ideas?